# DirectX9 Access violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx, access-violation, directx-9

I'm not sure quite how to debug this, and I'd really appreciate some help.

When I exit the program using the X, I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF854D4E797 (d3d9.dll) in directxtut.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000040400058.

The call stack shows the problem is occurring at line 195, d3d-Release();

Thanks in advance!

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the Direct3D Library files
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

// global declarations
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    // the pointer to the Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;    // the pointer to the vertex buffer
LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 i_buffer = NULL;     // the pointer to the index buffer

// function prototypes
void initD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void render_frame();        // renders a single frame
void cleanD3D();            // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void init_graphics();       // 3D declarations
void init_light();          // sets up the light and the material

struct CUSTOMVERTEX {FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DVECTOR NORMAL;};
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL)

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "WindowClass", "Jonathan's Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    initD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        render_frame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    cleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;    // automatically run the z-buffer
    d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;  // 16-bit pixel format for the z-buffer

    // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp stuct
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);

    init_graphics();    // call the function to initialize the models
    init_light();       // call the function to initialize the light and material

    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE);                       // turn on the 3D lighting
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);               // both sides of the triangles
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);                        // turn on the z-buffer
    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(50, 50, 50));   //turn on ambient light
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    // select which vertex format to use
    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

    // set the view transform
    D3DXMATRIX matView; // the view transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
                       &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 8.0f, 25.0f),    // the camera position
                       &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), // the look-at position
                       &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);         // set the view transform to matView

    // set the projection transform
    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;   // the projection transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                               D3DXToRadian(45),                                // the horizontal field of view
                               (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT,     // aspect ratio
                               1.0f,                                                // the near view-plane
                               100.0f);                                         // the far view-plane
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection);     // set the projection

    // an ever-increasing float value
    static float index = 0.0f;
    index += 0.03f;

    // set the world transform
    D3DXMATRIX matRotateY;      // a matrix to store the rotation for each triangle
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, index);    // the rotation matrix
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &(matRotateY));   // set the world transform

    // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
    d3ddev->SetIndices(i_buffer);

    // draw the model
    d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 24, 0, 12);

    d3ddev->EndScene();

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void cleanD3D(void)
{
    v_buffer->Release();    // close and release the vertex buffer
    i_buffer->Release();    //close and release the index buffer
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D *****HERE IS WHERE THE PROGRAM BREAKS*****
}


// this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
void init_graphics(void)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX
    struct CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] = 
    {
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },      // side 1
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },

        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },    // side 2
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },

        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },      // side 3
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },

        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },    // side 4
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },

        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },      // side 5
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },

        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },    // side 6
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(10*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                               0,
                               CUSTOMFVF,
                               D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                               &v_buffer,
                               NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();

    // create the indices using an int array
    short indices[] = 
    {
        0, 1, 2,        // side 1
        2, 1, 3,
        4, 5, 6,        // side 2
        6, 5, 7,
        8, 9, 10,       // side 3
        10, 9, 11,
        12, 13, 14,     // side 4
        14, 13, 15,
        16, 17, 18,     // side 5
        18, 17, 19,
        20, 21, 22,     // side 6
        22, 21, 23,
    };

    // create an index buffer interface called i_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(18*sizeof(short),
                              0,
                              D3DFMT_INDEX16,
                              D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                              &i_buffer,
                              NULL);

    //lock the i_buffer and load the indices into it
    i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    i_buffer->Unlock();
}

// this is the function that sets up the lights and materials
void init_light()
{
    D3DLIGHT9 light;        // create the light struct
    D3DMATERIAL9 material;  // create the material struct

    ZeroMemory(&light, sizeof(light));                  // clear out the light struct for use
    light.Type = D3DLIGHT_DIRECTIONAL;                  // make the light type directional light
    light.Diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);  // set the light's colour
    light.Direction = D3DXVECTOR3(-1.0f, -0.3f, -1.0f); // set the light's direction

    d3ddev->SetLight(0, &light);    // send the light struct properties to light #0
    d3ddev->LightEnable(0, TRUE);   // turn on light #0

    ZeroMemory(&material, sizeof(D3DMATERIAL9));        // clear out the struct for use
    material.Diffuse = D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   // set diffuse colour to white
    material.Ambient = D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);   // set ambient colour to white

    d3ddev->SetMaterial(&material); // set the globally-used material to &material
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but you tell the VertexBuffer to store 10 Vertices, but you put way more into it. My guess is, when you close the app, the memory gets corrupted.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly it (and IndexBuffer as well), I had forgotten to change them from a previous project. Thank you!